# Web API Save as PDF

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API used to save some generated PDFs.
I use the following code:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("getfile")]
public HttpResponseMessage GenerateFile(RequestView requestView)
{
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\sample.pdf", FileMode.Open) { Position = 0 })
{
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Sample.pdf" };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Sample.pdf";
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
}

return result;
}
```

But what i get is:

[image]

The response looks like:

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ

1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj
.
.
.
```

And the headers:

[image]

Does anyone have any clues related to this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please share an httpresponse from your application (network tab in chrome)

Comment: @n.piskunov added on question.

Comment: You've added just a body? It would be better the whole HTTP-response with all headers, status code, url etc. Btw have you tried returning FileStreamResult/FileContentResult? return File(...) (NET CORE?);

Comment: + Try specifying correct filename with extension - Sample.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Set response content to `ByteArrayContent` instead of `StreamContent`, Also make sure to add `.pdf` extention to `result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Sample.pdf";`

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("getfile")]
public HttpResponseMessage GenerateFile(RequestView requestView)
{
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\sample.pdf", FileMode.Open) { Position = 0 })
{
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Sample.pdf" };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Sample.pdf";
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: how you are trying, which tool you use to test it?

Comment: I have a Web API where i generate the PDF and return the response to UI.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I notice: one is that you're setting the content length. This shouldn't be required and I'd remove it.

Secondly, you don't provide FileStream constructor parameters for things like FileAccess.  I'd replace that with this, which should achieve what you need:

```
var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\sample.pdf");
```